# Angular JS from rs.send()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im generating some html code with angular in it, lets say it look something like this

```
exports.someApi = function(req,res){
  res.send('<p>some html {{ "ENTER-PASSWORD" | translate }} </p>');
}
```

and in my controller im doing this

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someapi'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
      $('.testPrint').html(data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

the problem is, I get resposne rigth, but angular code is not executed it print this in html

```
some html {{ "ENTER-PASSWORD" | translate }}
```

it should write some html enter password

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to go with Angular. Specifically, `$(...).html(data)` will set the data directly to DOM, bypassing Angular's compilation step. This step is where the "magic" happens" (i.e. in your case the `{{...}}` get bound to the model).

Some ways to do it:

- Make a directive and use `templateUrl: "/someapi"`. When the directive is to be displayed, Angular will load `/someApi` and compile it.
- Use `ng-include="'/someApi'"` (note single quotes within double quotes; this is intentional). Maybe together with `ng-if` to hide the content when not wanted.
- The [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) provides advanced facilities for subview navigation that may suit your needs.

A must-read is [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).